# Discord.js cannot read property

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to code a bot that will send a message when someone joins a voice channel. Code and error are below.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");

const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.login(config.BOT_TOKEN);

bot.once('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Bot ready, logged in as ${bot.user.tag}!`);
})

bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    const newUserChannel = newMember.voice.channelID
    const oldUserChannel = oldMember.voice.channelID
    const textChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get('766783720312537089')

    if (newUserChannel === '764231813248843806') {
        textChannel.send(`${newMember.user.username} (${newMember.id}) has joined the channel`)
    } else if (oldUserChannel === '764231813248843806' && newUserChannel !== '764231813248843806') {
        textChannel.send(`${newMember.user.username} (${newMember.id}) has left the channel`)
    }
})
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'channelID' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy to solve. The problem is that `voiceStateUpdate` does indeed take two variables, however they are not `oldMember, newMember` but `oldState, newState`.

As usual with functions it doesn't really matter what you call them but it makes more sense to use `oldState, newState` because they are a [`voiceState`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState). As such they do not have a `voice` property.

So to fix this, all you have to do is use the correct voiceState properties.

```
const newUserChannel = newState.channelID;
const oldUserChannel = oldState.channelID;
```

*Note: `newState.user` is also not a thing, however it does provide you with the `member` object so I suggest you use that instead.*

EDIT: Your entire code should look a little something like this.

```
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
    const newUserChannel = newState.channelID;
    const oldUserChannel = oldState.channelID;
    const textChannel = newState.guild.channels.cache.get('766783720312537089');
    
    if (newUserChannel === '764231813248843806') {
        textChannel.send(`${newState.member.user.username} (${newState.id}) has joined the channel`)
    } else if (oldUserChannel === '764231813248843806' && newUserChannel !== '764231813248843806') {
        textChannel.send(`${newState.member.user.username} (${newState.id}) has left the channel`)
    }

});
```

Comment: I am now getting this error: 'ReferenceError: newState is not defined'

Comment: Have you changed the names at the top of your function?

Comment: Ahh I have fixed that but now getting this error: 'ReferenceError: message is not defined'

Comment: yes because you don't have a `message` object. You can however access the `guild`  object via the `voiceState` object that you do have access to.

Comment: Would you be able to update your answer with the correct code so I can mark it as the answer

Comment: Thank you! I have another small question. `textChannel.send("<@&${774349004870778920}> ${newState.member.user.username} is now in the channel")` I am using this to try and mention a role but it keeps sending `@deleted-role` in discord

Comment: well, that means the role doesn't exist. What you can do is get the role first and then send that. You do that with `newState.guild.roles.cache.get('ID here')`

Comment: I tried to use let `myRole = newState.guild.roles.cache.get("774349004870778920");` and `myRole.name` but it just prints `@rolename` doesnt actually mention the role

Comment: leave out the `<@&>`. Just do `${myRole}`

Comment: Yes that works thank you! can you provide a way that a user can click a reaction that will add them to a role? i really do appreciate all your help

Comment: why don't you try it yourself first? ;) Also, if you want to ask me more questions please hit me up on discord, this is not the place for that. Worthy Alpaca#2063